# boost async_accept not working with the boost asio use_future option

Tags: sockets, c++11, boost-asio, future

I want to listen on a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` with a timeout. For this, I am using the `std::future::wait_for` function. Below is my code:

```
std::optional<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> server::listen()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io_service);
    std::future<void> accept_status = acceptor.async_accept(
        sock, boost::asio::use_future);
    if (accept_status.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(10)) == std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        // I hope there's no race-condition between
        // accepting a connection and calling cancel
        acceptor.cancel();
        std::cerr << "Timeout" << std::endl;
        return {};
    }
    std::cerr << "Accepted a connection" << std::endl;
    return {std::move(sock)};
}
```

This is not working though: the client is able to connect, but I still get a timeout. Which means that the future object and the asynchronous accept function aren't communicating. What am I missing?

I am using Boost version `1.65`.

For `Explorer_N`, following is a complete program that does not work the way I expect:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void server_listen() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 31132);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    std::future<void> accept_status = acceptor.async_accept(
            socket, boost::asio::use_future);
    while(true) {
        if(accept_status.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(10)) == std::future_status::timeout) {
            acceptor.cancel();
            std::cerr << "Timeout\n";
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    // if I replace the lines starting from the async_accept call
    // by just the following, everything works as expected
    // acceptor.accept(socket);
    std::cout << "Accepted a connection\n";
    while(true) {
    }
}

void client_connect() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(*resolver.resolve({"127.0.0.1", std::to_string(31132)}));
    socket.connect(endpoint);
    std::cout << "Connected to server\n";
    while(true) {
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread server(server_listen);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::thread client(client_connect);
    while(true) {
    }
}
```

Compiled by `g++ -std=c++17 <program>.cpp -lpthread -lboost_system -o <program>`.

The output I get is:

```
Connected to server
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
Timeout
...
```

Comment: Did you increase the timeout and check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your claims:

"future object and the asynchronous accept function aren't communicating" -- not possible.

"the client is able to connect, but I still get a timeout.", -- your client connecting to a listener is one event and executing completion-handler (setting promise) is an another event.

So connection could've accepted at 9th second and callback would have scheduled to run at 11th second (for instance).

Remember, we are dealing with asynchronous ops, so making absolute prediction on future events is not something  right I would say.

apart form that

```
// I hope there's no race-condition between
        // accepting a connection and calling cancel
        acceptor.cancel();
        std::cerr << "Timeout" << std::endl;
        return {};
```

`acceptor.cancel();` just collect the pending waiters, and complete them with `ec` set to `operation_aborted`, if the handlers are already out to completion event queue, then cancel() is a no-op

Extending my answer based on OP's recent edit:

```
using namespace std;

void server_listen() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 31132);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    auto work = make_work_guard(io_service);
    using type= std::decay_t<decltype(work)>;
    std::thread io([&](){io_service.run();});
    std::future<void> accept_status = acceptor.async_accept(
            socket, boost::asio::use_future);
    if(accept_status.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(10)) == std::future_status::timeout) {
        acceptor.cancel();
        std::cerr << "Timeout\n";
        work.~type();
        //break;
    } else {
        std::cout<<"future is ready\n";
        work.~type();
       // break;
    }

    io.join();
    // if I replace the lines starting from the async_accept call
    // by just the following, everything works as expected
    // acceptor.accept(socket);
    std::cout << "Accepted a connection\n";

}

void client_connect() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(*resolver.resolve({"127.0.0.1", std::to_string(31132)}));
    socket.connect(endpoint);
    std::cout << "Connected to server\n";

}
enter code here
int main() {
    std::thread server(server_listen);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::thread client(client_connect);
    server.join(); client.join();
}
```

There are many things to take care of in your program (avoid unnecessary spin-loop, don't forgot to either join or detach the `std::thread` and make sure you call `io_service::run` when you use `async*` version)

```
Start
Connected to server
future is ready
Accepted a connection
0
Finish
```

Comment: Hi @Explorer_N, I have edited the question to add a sample program. Can you test it on your system?

Comment: Do you anywhere see  `io_service.run()`?

Comment: Thanks. I should have looked into how to properly use boost io service with asynchronous calls.